# How to get the compositor instance while handling XamlCompositionBrushBase.OnConnected in a WinUI-3 desktop app

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt, winui-3

Following [this c++ example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.xamlcompositionbrushbase?view=winrt-22621#examples) i'm trying to create a custom brush in a WinUI 3 desktop application but i cannot find out how to get a [compositor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositor?view=winrt-22621) instance from within the [OnConnected Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.xamlcompositionbrushbase.onconnected?view=winrt-22621).
The example uses

```
Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Window::Current().Compositor()
```

but [Current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window.current?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1#microsoft-ui-xaml-window-current) (and [CoreWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window.corewindow?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1#microsoft-ui-xaml-window-corewindow)) are [always null for desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1#properties).

How can i get the [compositor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositor?view=winrt-22621) instance needed to create brushes?

Comment: I guess you'll need to create a dispatcher queue controller ([`CreateDispatcherQueueController`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dispatcherqueue/nf-dispatcherqueue-createdispatcherqueuecontroller)), though frankly, I don't know what WinUI 3's Dispatcher-of-the-Week is this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as often it gets easy as soon as the matching [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.media.compositiontarget.getcompositorforcurrentthread?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1) is found:

> In XAML apps, we recommend that you call
> [ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(UIElement)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.hosting.elementcompositionpreview.getelementvisual) to get a
> Composition [Visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.composition.visual), and get the Compositor from the visual's
> [Compositor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.composition.compositionobject.compositor) property. In cases where you don't have access to a
> UIElement (for example, if you create a [CompositionBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.composition.compositionbrush) in a class
> library), you can call CompositionTarget.GetCompositorForCurrentThread
> to get the Compositor instead.

[Related issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2609).

[Related Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/3376).